# SOQL not returning list when if statement written

Tags: apex, custom-controller

I have a class that is trying to query the email submitted in a VF form and I have no errors on the dev console but when I go to run my test class I am getting an error stating that the list is returning no results. This class is supposed to create a case and assign it to the correct queue once it is filled in. The part that is not passing the test class is that we want to check and see if that email is part of a contacts email, if so then we want to update the contact id look up to that contact. I put in there to check and see if we have one against that controller and if there is not then to have it be null. Wondering what I might be missing on this?

Apex:

```
public class attachController{

public case objcase{get;set;}
public contact cont{get;set;}
public Attachment myAttachment{get;set;}
public string fileName{get;set;}
public Blob fileBody{get;set;}

RecordType recordId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Product_Case'];
Id recId = (recordId != null) ? recordId.Id : null;

Group queueId = [select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperNAME = 'Product_Support_Case_Queue' LIMIT 1];
Id ownerId = (queueId != null) ? queueId.Id : null;
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact limit 1];


//string recId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Product Case').getRecordTypeId();

public attachController(Apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
{
    objcase = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    myAttachment = new Attachment();
}
public PageReference submit(){

    Contact con = [Select Id, email from contact where Email =: objcase.Email__c Limit 1];
    String conid = (con != null) ? con.Id : null;

    if (fileName != null){
        objcase.RecordTypeId = recId;
        objcase.ownerId = ownerId;
        //objcase.contactID = conId;
        insert objcase;

        myAttachment = new Attachment();
        Integer i=0;
        myAttachment .clear();
        myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
        myAttachment.Name = fileName ;
        myAttachment.ParentId = objcase.id;            
        insert myAttachment;
    } else {
        objcase.RecordTypeId = recId;
        objcase.ownerId = ownerId;
        //objcase.contactID = conId;
        insert objcase;

    }             
    pagereference pr = Page.thankYouForSubmittingYourProductCase;                          
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class attachController_Test {

@isTest
static void test1(){

    //Id recId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Product Case').getRecordTypeId();

    Case caseObj = new Case( Email__c = 'Test@test.com',
                            Subject = 'Phone',
                            What_are_you_experiencing__c = 'I have a feature request',
                            Location_of_issue__c = 'Campaigns',
                            Source_Type__c = 'Source',
                            Campaign_Source_ID__c = '123456',
                            Description = 'test from Mr. Testerson');


    Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Attachment Body');
    Attachment attachObj = new Attachment(
        Name='Unit Test Attachment',
        body=bodyBlob,
        parentId=caseObj.id);      


    ApexPages.StandardController stdCtr = new ApexPages.StandardController(caseObj );
    attachController attachControllerObj = new attachController(stdCtr);
    attachControllerObj .fileName = 'your file name';
    attachControllerObj .fileBody = Blob.valueOf('your file name');
    attachControllerObj .submit();  



    Case caseObj1 = new Case(Email__c = 'Test2@test.com',
                             Subject = 'Phone',
                             What_are_you_experiencing__c = 'I have a feature request',
                             Location_of_issue__c = 'Campaigns',
                             Source_Type__c = 'Source',
                             Campaign_Source_ID__c = '123456',
                             Description = 'test from Mr. Testerson');


    ApexPages.StandardController stdCtr1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(caseObj1 );
    attachController attachControllerObj1 = new attachController(stdCtr1);
    attachControllerObj1.submit();  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Contact con = [Select Id, email from contact where Email =: objcase.Email__c Limit 1];
```

This will throw a QueryException if no rows are found. You need to make a list first, or use a loop. Here's how I usually write this:

```
Contact con;
for(Contact record: [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = :objcase.Email__c LIMIT 1]) {
  con = record;
}
Id conId = con == null? null: con.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That did the trick.